# Why doesn't my new ceiling fan's light work from the pull chain?

Tags: ceiling-fan

I connected a ceiling fan/light and put white together then the blacks and capped off red.

The fan works but light doesn't turn on from the chain. Why?

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se], please take the [tour]. I've edited your question to simplify the title and to actually, you know, ask a question in the body. If I've missed something important, please feel free to [edit] again to correct any mistakes I may have made...

Comment: Picture of the wiring (switch and fixture boxes) would help. What model fan?

Comment: Does your fan have a blue wire for the light?  if so, did you connect it to the blacks?

Answer (score 2):

The fan and light are often fed by two separate power wires, so the light can be controlled from a wall switch and the fan can be controlled from the chain, or other such independent setups. The fan and light have a common white wire.

Often the fan power wire is black and the light power wire is some other color, perhaps blue.

If you have no other power source, like a wall switch, that you want to control the light separately with, and you want both the fan and the light controlled by chains at the fan body, wire both the fan black and the light other-color wire to the house black wire. The fan/light white and house white go together, as you have now.

If you did want the light controlled by the wall switch (which probably powers the red wire) attach the light power wire to the red.